# Converting array of objects into array of strings

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I'm working on an app where I need to pass an array of strings to a backend service something like

```
const ids = []; 
for (let i = 0; i < pIds.length; i++) { 
  ids.push(pIds[i].id);
} 
// pIds is an array of objects [{id: 2, name: 'dd'}]


this.webClient = new Frisbee({
  baseURI: `${Secrets.url_host}/api/v1`,
  headers: {
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
});

getData({ continuation = 1, q = '', ids = '' }) {
 return this.webClient.get('/whatever', {
  body: {
    'platform_ids': ids,
  },
}).then(getContent);
```

}

after running this code if get an array of ids [2,3] for example

but when I pass it to the backend (ruby on rails ) it arrive like that

```
[{"0"=>"1", "1"=>"2"}]
```

What can I do to get it as ["1", "2"]? I've tried many solutions but nothing works.

Comment: Can you show the code where you call your function for passing values?

Comment: You probably send pIds instead of ids

Comment: No I'm sending ids ,

Comment: Did you JSON.parse the data you send to the ROR backend before using it?

Comment: How are you passing it to your back-end service?

Comment: __when I pass it to the backend__ - show the full ajax code.

Comment: @AhmedAli what is inside the `this.webClient.get()` function? where it is defined? Show the full code please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't solve it , so i changed my backend to accept string with "," and parsing it to array in the backend .

for example

```
const ids = {id: 3, id: 4};
const idsForBackend = ids.map(id => id.id).join();
```